# Performance difference between running program by Visual Studio and by local ( using WriteableBitmap to draw in WPF)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, performance, writeablebitmap

I have a WPF application for drawing (Like Microsoft Paint) and I use WriteableBitmap and subscribe mouse event to do that.

It works perfectly and the ink tracks my mouse immediately when I run the program by Visual Studio no matter in debug mode or release mode

However, I get bad performance when I drawing by running the program exe file (*\bin\Release\net5.0-windows\oooo.exe* OR *\bin\Debug\net5.0-windows\oooo.exe*). the ink is drawn slower and has some delay after the mouse moving when drawing.

The difference (click to view gifs):

- [Running the program by Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhGUY.gif)
- [Running the program exe file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ur9uC.gif)

Even I build this application on local, I got the same bad result. Is there any thing I can fix this?

The code is as follows:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="paint_test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="900" Width="1600"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas Name="MainCanvas" Background="Bisque"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace paint_test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainCanvas.Children.Add(new PaintCanvas((int)MainCanvas.ActualWidth, (int)MainCanvas.ActualHeight));
        }
    }
}
```

**PaintCanvas.cs**

```
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace paint_test
{
    public class PaintCanvas : System.Windows.Controls.Image
    {
        WriteableBitmap fullWriteableBmp;
        int paintingSize = 10;
        Color paintingColor = Colors.Blue;

        public PaintCanvas(int width, int height)
        {
            RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(this, BitmapScalingMode.NearestNeighbor);
            RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(this, EdgeMode.Aliased);
            fullWriteableBmp = BitmapFactory.New(width, height);
            Source = fullWriteableBmp;

            MouseDown += PaintCanvas_MouseDown;
            MouseMove += PaintCanvas_MouseMove;
        }

        private void PaintCanvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed) return;
            DrawPixel(e);
        }


        private void PaintCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed) return;
            DrawPixel(e);
        }

        private void DrawPixel(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            int x1 = (int)e.GetPosition(this).X - (paintingSize / 2);
            int y1 = (int)e.GetPosition(this).Y - (paintingSize / 2);
            int x2 = (int)e.GetPosition(this).X + (paintingSize / 2);
            int y2 = (int)e.GetPosition(this).Y + (paintingSize / 2);
            fullWriteableBmp.FillEllipse(x1, y1, x2, y2, paintingColor);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Because of missing code information. I could only guess that it might be because of a refresh issue. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23673733/16764901) maybe help you.

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT Thanks for your quick response! I think [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23673733/how-to-clear-a-writeablebitmap) is not the same issue, thanks anyway. I have uploaded some code, please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: It shows the following errors:`The name 'BitmapFactory' does not exist in the current context` and `'WriteableBitmap' does not contain a definition for 'FillEllipse' and no accessible extension method 'FillEllipse' accepting a first argument of type 'WriteableBitmap' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`   What type of WPF are you, have you added any nugets? I created it under .net 6.0.

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT I added a nuget called '[WriteableBitmapEx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WriteableBitmapEx/)' (version: 1.6.8), and I created it under .net 5.0